# Loader service with multiple types of targets

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

Assume this Loader service:

**html:**

```
<div class="loader" ng-class="(loader) ? 'show' : 'hide'"></div>
```

**service:**

```
app.service('Loader', function ($rootScope) {
  var _number = 0;
  this.reset = function () {
    $rootScope.loader = false;
    _number = 0;
    return this;
  };

  this.show = function () {
    _number++;
    $rootScope.loader = true;
    return this;
  };

  this.hide = function () {
    _number--;
    if (_number <= 0) {
      $rootScope.loader = false;
    }
    return this;
  };

});
```

which takes the number of requests in process into account.
 Calling `Loader.show()` before `$http` requests and `Loader.hide()` after response received works fine as a loader service but it's just one global loader. 
I need to show loader element:

- inside index.html as global loader for loading content of each view
- inside buttons for submit events
- inside popups for loading content of them

I'm looking for a good way to determine which loader element should be shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I didn't received an answer, I figured out a way myself. I'm publishing it, may be some one need it. 
I separated the loader in two types, a global and a particular witch accepts an element as parameter. and adding a class name "loading-icon", and some states for different types of inputs:

```
app.service('Loader', function ($rootScope) {
  var _number = 0;
  this.reset = function () {
  };

  this.gloabal = {};
  this.gloabal.show = function () {
  };
  this.gloabal.hide = function () {
  };

  this.particular = {};
  // target must be angular element or JS selected DOM element
  this.particular.show = function (target) {
    angular.element(target).addClass('loading');
  };
  this.particular.hide = function (target) {
   angular.element(target).removeClass('loading');
  };
});
```

styles :

```
.loading-icon:after
{
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: ('spinner.gif') no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

calling:

```
var button = docuemnt.getElementById('submit-button');
Loader.particular.show(button);
```

or

```
Loader.global.show();
```

Comment: I appreciate any better answers.